# Why "lets stack together" is nsfw?

Tags: meaning-in-context

During a gameplay, there was move where I could choose to piggyback with my partners.

[image]

So I suggested to them, "Let's stack together".

Then one of my friends jokingly said I was a pervert because I was telling people to stack. I didn't understand what she meant.

I felt stupid questioning her on this, because she's from an English-speaking country.

In what context has "Let's stack together" become sexual/nsfw (not safe for work)?

Google shows me only a form of data structure in Computer Science.

Also, can anyone suggest an alternative way to suggest piggybacking gracefully?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't just say, "Let's piggyback," or even, "Let's be partners."  Is there some reason you want to say something different? *Stack*, and especially *stack together*, is not very idiomatic in this context. Whenever something doesn't sound normal, it's common to apply some kind of unusual connotation to it.

Comment: Imagination! What is wrong with your imagination?

Answer (score 2):

To stack things means to put them on top of each other vertically, like a stack of plates.

[image]

When one person is stacked on top of another person, their genital areas are normally near each other, so it takes on a sexual connotation. Or if one head is toward the other person's feet, they're in a "69" position, which is also sexual.

Piggybacking is not stacking, because it's not a vertical arrangement. Also, stacking usually means that you can have numerous items in this arrangement. But except for acrobatic troops, I think people would have a hard time piggybacking on a piggybacker.

Comment: It's a stretch. The pic as shown is obviously not a sexual position (unless the person on the bottom is a satyr). I'd honestly guess the friend is just trying (awkwardly) to make a joke, but wow, that's quite a reach.

Comment: I know the picture isn't sexual. But describing it as "stack together" doesn't really apply to it.

Comment: Eh, it's not any less "stacking" than lying on top of each other horizontally is.

Comment: Piggybacking is one person on the *back* of someone else, not on *top* of someone else. However, I admit that human pyramids also could be described as stacking.

Comment: Anyway, I'm just trying to explain how the person who said it was NSFW was interpreting it.

Comment: Still can we agree that the comment is an intentional misinterpretation in a poor attempt to make a joke?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know how intentional it was.